A weird scifi/horror movie with mind controlling brain in a jar and some erotic scenes
This is a movie I've seen a long time ago. It was a weird mix of SciFi, Horror and Thriller, I think - but it might have just been a soft porno with me mainly remembering pieces of the story ;)
Speaking of which, there was a brain in a jar that had mind control capabilities. It occasionally took people over and had them do stuff, at least once that meant two people having sex and I think it tried a few times to get someone killed - not sure if it succeeded. I think it belonged to a scientist/teacher who brought it home and placed it on his desk (possibly driven by the brain). No idea what brain's overall plans were, but there was some ongoing suspense on whether people affected would find out about who was behind everything.
I've seen the movie at the end of the 80s or beginning of the 90s. It looked American and most likely was a TV / direct-to-DVD...err VHS production.
It was in color as far as I remember and roughly looked like it played in the 80s.

@theguest it was in color

Alright, I asked wise old Google directly again. This time I found it, maybe because your questions helped me dig out some details, so thanks. 
Anyway, it was Possessed by the Night: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Possessed_by_the_Night
An erotic thriller from 1994 where a horror writer buys a jar containing a monster (it looks like a deformed brain though, I'd claim). 

The jar thing helps him write horror books/scripts, but also makes him more aggressive and sexually aroused, which makes for some mix of both scenes... (which I don't show here^^)

There is also a secretary who wants to steal his script for his greedy agent and in the end there's a lot of distrust and some murdering climax. 
Haven't rewatched it yet, but the jar thing is definitely what I remembered, the visual style matches and the suspense/thriller/adult movie mix fit as well. No idea if it is actually any good, we'll see. Still, thanks for all who answered.
And as honourable mentions, two movies I came across that are hilarious as well, and may be what someone else is looking for when stumbling over this question: 1) The Brain from 1988



and 2) Tammy and the T-Rex, where in the very end, Denise Richards does a striptease for a brain in a jar:
http://www.cracked.com/article_24783_7-sex-scenes-so-insane-theyll-melt-your-brain.html



